Why is shift operator group action of cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_p$ free depending whether or not $p$ is prime?
While reading one scientific article, I stumbled upon the following statement without explanation:
Let the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_p$ act on topological space $\left(\prod_{k=1}^p{\mathbb{R}^n}\right)\setminus\mathbb{D}$ where $\mathbb{D} =  \{(v,\ldots,v), v\in\mathbb{R}^n\} $ as follows (let $\omega$ be a generator):
$$\omega(v_1,\ldots,v_p) = (v_2,\ldots,v_p,v_1)$$
This action is free if $p$ is prime and is not free if $p$ is not prime. I immediately thought that this action is always free.
Can somebody please help me get a counterexample element if $p$ is not prime (e.g. simplest would be $p=4$), because I just cannot derive it.
Ps: for anybody interested, article is "On a topological generalization of a theorem of Tverberg" (I. Barany, S. B. Shlosman and A. Szucs)

I'm not sure I understand your group action. Do you intend for $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to act on $p$-tuples $(v_1, \dots, v_p)$ in the natural way by cyclic permutations?

Yes, exactly. So $1.(v_1,\ldots,v_p) = (v_2, \ldots, v_p, v_1)$ and $2.(v_1,\ldots,v_p) = (v_3, \ldots, v_p, v_1, v_2)$ and so on. Sorry I had an index typo in my question.

Let $n = 1$ and $p = 4$. Then $\omega^2(1, 2, 1, 2) = \omega(2, 1, 2, 1) = (1, 2, 1, 2)$ and the action is not free. This does not happen for $p$ prime since $\omega^n(v) = v$ for some $v$ implies that $n \mid p$.

Thank you! Regarding your second statement, the simplest way to prove that $w^n(v)=v$ implies $n|p$ is to suppose that $n$ doesn't divide $p$? Then you get $w(v)=v$ or $v\in\mathbb{D}$ which is obviously a contradiction?

@toxic Personally I think the clearest way to reason is via the orbit-stabilizer theorem: If $G$ is a finite group acting on a set $X$, then you have $|G.x| = [G : G_x]$ for all $x \in X$ where $G.x$ denotes the orbit of $x$ and $G_x \leq G$ its stabilizer subgroup. Thus, if $G = \mathbb{Z} / p$ for some prime $p$ you always have that $|G.x| = 1$ or $p$, the first case of which corresponds to $v \in \mathbb{D}$ and the second to $\mathbb{Z} / p$ acting freely on that orbit.
